# models of PA which are isomorphic but not elementarily equivalent?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, peano-arithmetic

On page 164 of his book **Models of Peano Arithmetic**, Kaye states Friedman's Theorem:

Let $M{\vDash}PA$ be nonstandard and countable, let $a\in M$ and let $n\in {\mathbb N}$.  Then there is a proper initial segment $I\subseteq_c M$ ($\subseteq_c$ means "cofinal in") containing $a$ such that $I\cong M$ and $I<_{\Sigma_n} M$.

However, on the next page he writes "Nor can we expect in general to get initial segments $I$ with $M\cong I < M$ and $M\neq I$, i.e., elementary for all formulas.  For example if $M=K_T$ (where $T\neq Th({\mathbb N})$ is a complete extension of PA) then $M$ has no proper elementary substructures, and so certainly has no proper elementary initial segments!"

I am confused.  If two models in the same language are isomorphic, are they not elementarily equivalent?  Of course the converse need not be true.

An isomorphism of models is a bijective homomorphism of the language's algebraic portion (constants and functions) which preserves **and reflects** all relations of the language (Hodges, **Model Theory**, p5).  Therefore by induction on the structure of any ${\mathcal L}_{\omega,\omega}$ formula, the isomorphism will both preserve and reflect it.  So an isomorphism preserves **all** formulas (Hodges, Theorem 2.4.3(c)).

If the proper initial segment is isomorphic as a model to the entire model, how could any first-order sentence possibly be true in one and not in the other?

Thanks,

- a

Comment: Probable typo: $\subseteq_c$ should be $\subseteq_e$, where $e$ is for _initial_ or _end_. (The typo is in the OP's question, not in Kaye's book).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a major difference between *elementary equivalence* and *elementary embedding*. Moreover, in this case, the actual embedding is somewhat ambiguous. First, let me recap some often confused terminology.

Two models are *elementary equivalent* if they satisfy the same first-order sentences. Any two isomorphic models are always elementary equivalent. An *elementary embedding* is a map j:A→B such that, for all first-order formulas φ(v<sub>1</sub>,...,v<sub>k</sub>) and all a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>k</sub> ∈ A, A ⊧ φ(a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>k</sub>) iff B ⊧ φ(j(a<sub>1</sub>),...,j(a<sub>k</sub>)). An isomorphism is always an elementary embedding.

The notation A ≺ B means that A is an *elementary submodel* of B, i.e. the *inclusion map* A  ⊆ B is an elementary embedding from A into B. In your context, the isomorphism (or its inverse) is *not* the proposed elementary embedding, it is the inclusion map which is in question: it is elementary for Σ<sub>n</sub> formulas, but not elementary for all first-order formulas.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I stupidly took "≺" to mean "elementarily embedded in" rather than "elementary submodel of".  Must memorize more symbols...


Comment: It can be very confusing! I've seen j:A ≺ B to mean that j is an elementary embedding... 